# how get text after br and wrap it in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have this code:

```html
<td class="tabledata">
  <img>
  <span class="someclass"></span>
  <br> text
</td>
```

I want to get the text and wrap it in a div and give it a class name.

I've tried:

```js
$(".tabledata").html().split("<br />")[1];

$(".tabledata").each(function() {
  $(this).nextAll("br").get(0).wrap('<div></div>')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td class="tabledata">
  <img>
  <span class="someclass"></span>
  <br> text
</td>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
$($(".tabledata").children('br').get(0).nextSibling).wrap('<div />');
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/jWnCE/)

If you want to wrap all the direct text nodes children of the td then

```
$(".tabledata").contents().filter(function(){
    return this.nodeType == 3 && $.trim($(this).text()) != '';
}).wrap('<div />');
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/g4jmv/)